# Active Admin add + button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model Post which have two attributes `title` - `data-type string`  and `description`- `data-type array`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
   permit_params :title, :description

   form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

1. Value of `title` is saving properly but value of `description` is not saving through the form. How to save array field?
2. Can I put `Add more` button for `description` in active admin?

Comment: Question not clear.please be more specifc. Add form, output your expecting

Comment: If I am adding values from the browser form, only `title` is saving but `description` is not. data-type of title is string & data-type of description is array

Comment: why you are using array for description?

Comment: I can change description to string. But any other attribute can also be array.

Comment: There is no standard Formtastic input for an array.  You can try googling for `Formtastic array input` for ideas on building your own custom input.  Perhaps, however, you can make description a separate model and use a has_many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to change name to accept array**

```
f.input :description, input_html: { name: 'description[]' }
```

Comment: That did not work, do I have to change anything in `permit_params`

Comment: `permit_params :title, :description`

Comment: can u permit in this way permit_params :title, :description=>[]